# Storing keystrokes into text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I have taken a piece of code from https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html and modified it so that it stores keystrokes into a text file. However, I get the error message in the output:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'keyboard' from 'pynput'
```

Googling it brings up...

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
```

...but even this import is not compatible with my code. I have downloaded pynput for python3. The original code from the above link:

```
from pynput import keyboard
    def on_press(key):
        try:
            print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
    def on_release(key):
        print('{0} released'.format(key))
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False
    # Collect events until released
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

The modified code:

```
import pynput
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        try:
            f.print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            f.print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
def on_release(key):
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        f.print('{0} released'.format(key))
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False
# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Am I missing something that would allow the program to properly store the keystrokes into the text file?

Comment: Haven't you install the pynput module,right?I can run the first example without exception after I get the right indent.

Comment: pip3 install pynput and pip3 install keyboard are my commands in the terminal. I'm doing this from Visual Studio Code in Kali Linux VM.

Comment: @Pkd show complete error message. what is the name of your script?

Comment: /usr/bin/python3 /root/Testing6/Sample6_2/pynput.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Testing6/Sample6_2/pynput.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pynput
  File "/root/Testing6/Sample6_2/pynput.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pynput import keyboard
ImportError: cannot import name 'keyboard' from 'pynput' (/root/Testing6/Sample6_2/pynput.py)

Comment: Hm... are you running the script with `python3 file.py`? Just using python uses python 2 as far as I know.

Comment: Have you revised your ``pynput`` structure? You can reinstall ``pynput`` again.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing python3. I have reinstalled the pynput; requirements have already been satisfied

Comment: @Pkd change `/root/Testing6/Sample6_2/pynput.py` to  `/root/Testing6/Sample6_2/test_of_pynput.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st** of all, **DO NOT** name your Python files same as modules.

> ```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'keyboard' from 'pynput' (/root/Testing6/Sample6_2/pynput.py)
> ```

Here, Python is looking for `keyboard` from *your* pynput script, instead of the *actual* pynput module.
See the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Here, Python found a `pynput` module in the current directory, your script, which obviously isn't the one you want and it indeed does not have the `keyboard` module. So, you just need to rename it something else (ex. *mykeylogger.py*). Your current import code should work fine:

```
from pynput import keyboard
```

**2nd**, there is no `f.print`. FIle objects do not have a `print` method.
Change all those `f.print` to `f.write`.

```py
def on_press(key):
    with open("keylogger.txt", "a") as f:
        try:
            f.write('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            f.write('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))
```

**Last**, do take note that `pynput` has some [platform limitations](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html) that may cause it to *not* work. For Linux, you just have to make sure that:

> - An *X server* must be running.
> - The environment variable `$DISPLAY` must be set.

Your program runs fine after that.

```
$ python3 mykeylogger.py
aaabbb
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
...
KeyboardInterrupt
$ cat keylogger.txt
alphanumeric key a pressed'a' releasedalphanumeric key a pressed'a' releasedalphanumeric key a pressed'a' releasedalphanumeric key b pressed'b' releasedalphanumeric key b pressed'b' releasedalphanumeric key b pressed'b' releasedspecial key Key.enter pressedKey.enter releasedspecial key Key.ctrl pressedalphanumeric key  pressed
```